# Installshield 10 - Installing for All Users

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installshield

My application uses InstallSheild 10 to install the my application for 'all users'. When the user is logged in as USER1 and is an administrator on the machine, my program works fine for him. As soon as USER2 logs in, my software is not installed for him and windows starts the installer as soon as he logs on. Since this user (USER2) cannot find the msi file, windows keeps trying to install the software and aborts when it can't find the Msi.

Why does this happen? Anybody got a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things first: Enable [verbose logging](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/223300), test your scenario, and see what the log says it's looking for - it's possible you can fix your installation to not require a per-user auto-repair. Second, clarify whether you mean InstallShield X (ten years old now) or InstallShield 2010.

But regardless of the above, there's a good chance you can address this by enabling *Cache Msi Locally* (formerly *Cache Web Download* if you're on InstallShield X) in your release options. This will have setup.exe put the .msi file on the machine in a place where other accounts can typically use it.